# What's the difference between Welcome screen, Getting Started screen and Start Window?

Tags: gui-design, terminology

Microsoft Office has "Start Window":
[image: Microsoft Excel Start window]

Visual Studio also has "Start window":
[image: Visual Studio Start Window]

This is an example of welcome screen:
[image: Welcome screen]

And this is a getting Started Screen for LabView:
[image: LabView Getting Started]

What's the difference between the three in terms of Design and expected functionality?

Comment: Hello @ZiadMadkour, and welcome to UX.SE! Why are referring to these screens with different names in your question? Did you see various other resources naming these screens with the terms "Start Window", "Welcome Screen", and "Getting Started Screen" and are wondering if there's a difference?

Comment: @maxathousand Yes, Visual studio calls it **start window** and Microsoft Office calls it **start screen**, and LabView calls their screen **Getting Started** and the design I put for Welcome screen, some UI designer put it under this name (**Welcome Screen**).
so, yes, I'm wondering what's the difference between the three screens?

Comment: Ah. I'm not convinced there is a meaningful difference. I think these all serve the same purposes by helping the user begin their task with resuming where they left off or with beginning a new project. It seems people just use different terms for the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are generally the same thing and serve the same purpose. In some instances, some of these screens may have the role of reinforcing features/benefits before letting the users start a new task.

Comment: And the screens generally contains accelerators for commonly used functions, e.g. open recent files.